# How to get unique value from Realm database in swift

Tags: swift, realm, unique

I do news application in `swift` using `Realm database`. In my database have same news categories. How to get unique value from `Realm database`?
I use primary key

```
class News: Object {

 dynamic var newsID: String = ""
 dynamic var newsTitle: String = ""
 dynamic var newsFullText: String = ""
 dynamic var newsImage: String = ""
 dynamic var newsAutor: String = ""
 dynamic var newsCommentCount: String = ""
 dynamic var newsSeenCount: String = ""
 dynamic var newsDate: String = ""
 dynamic var newsCategory: String = ""

   override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "newsID"
   }
}
```

I'm try to get

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let menuName = realm.objects(News)
for i in menuName.filter("newsCategory") {
nameLabel.text = i.newsCategory
}
```

But it is not work.

Comment: are you using primary keys?

Comment: I update question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from Realm 3.10 it's now possible to

> Add Results.distinct(by:) / -[RLMResults
>   distinctResultsUsingKeyPaths:], which return a Results containing only
>   objects with unique values at the given key paths.

#### Old response - before Realm 3.10

It is not possible yet to obtain a "distinct"-like functonality from a Realm query (track the open issue [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1103))

However, there are some workarounds suggested in the thread I mentioned above (please read it to get the full context), by user `apocolipse` :

```
// Query all users
let allUsers = Realm().objects(User)

// Map out the user types
let allTypes = map(allUsers) { $0.type }

// Fun part: start with empty array [], add in element to reduced array if its not already in, else add empty array
let distinctTypes = reduce(allTypes, []) { $0 + (!contains($0, $1) ? [$1] : [] )
```

Or better yet, a different approach using `Set`s (by user `jpsim`):

```
let distinctTypes = Set(Realm().objects(User).valueForKey("type") as! [String])
```

Obviously the workarounds aren't as efficient as a direct DB query, so use with care (and testing under realistic load).